# How to set Location of Message Dialog in java?

Tags: java, dialog

In java, message dialogs open in middle of the Frame window by default in java. I want open the message dialog in specified location. Is it possible.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes is it possible using the setLocation method:

```
mydialog.setLocation(200,200);
```

But you must set the location before set the visible. Swing components can't dynamically re-generated after visibility. Just set the location before set visible to true.